# How do I open the user manual in GIMP?

Tags: gimp

I'm currently learning how to use GIMP for image editing and thought I'd try reading the user manual. So I clicked on **Help** --> **User Manual** --> **Basic Concepts** and this message popped up:

> Could not open 'https://docs.gimp.org/2.10/en/gimp-help.xml' for reading: An AppArmor policy prevents this sender from sending this message to this recipient;

[image: help message]

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi a snap app, is it generally better to install with apt?

Comment: That is an opinion based question. If you really need the latest version, go with snap (but there are PPAs too). Otherwise, the apt apps are generally faster, consume less space, and integrate much better with the rest of the system. Snap is gradually getting there, but it still has many issues. There are reasons why many users are not happy about Ubuntu's forceful inclusion of snaps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the error message, it seems that GIMP is installed as a snap app.

Installing the `apt` version should fix `AppArmor Policy` issues.

Open a terminal and enter the command

```
sudo snap remove gimp && sudo apt install gimp -y
```

Comment: What does the -y flag do?

Comment: @Fadi With the -y flag, `apt` would not again ask you whether you really want install or not. I am not sure if the -y flag works with snap also, that's why I did not add it there.