# How to install gimp-help locally on Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: apt, firefox, snap, gimp, helpfile

What do I have to do to be able to view the help pages of GIMP on Ubuntu 22.04?

I'm using the snap version of GIMP 2.10.30.

Answer (score 1):

1. Switch from snap to apt for reinstalling GIMP 2.10.30
2. `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt install gimp-help-common gimp-help-en`
3. Update the installed version of Firefox from 113 to 114.

Here's how I got there:

I was unable to display the help pages of GIMP 2.10.30, online as well as locally, on my laptop with Ubuntu 22.04. I had installed GIMP 2.10.30 via Ubuntu Software.

When I uninstalled the snap version of GIMP (from Ubuntu Software), and installed GIMP via the command `sudo apt install gimp` I was able to view the help pages online (after reading [How do I open the user manual in GIMP?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1359999/how-do-i-open-the-user-manual-in-gimp)).

And the solution for the locally stored help pages came eventually today, when I updated Firefox 113 to Firefox 114, both snap packages from Ubuntu Software.

To install the help pages locally I typed following commands:

`sudo apt update`

`sudo apt install gimp-help-common gimp-help-en`

which I found by reading [Cannot access GIMP help because AppArmor stops it](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1393876/cannot-access-gimp-help-because-apparmor-stops-it).

(If I remember well, in the snap version of GIMP the message that the manual wasn't locally installed was displayed after the two commands above (in Edit -> Preferences -> Help System) , but this changed when I uninstalled the snap version of GIMP and installed the apt version.)

The help pages were locally stored in the directory /usr/share/gimp/2.0/help/en. At first I wasn't aware that Firefox opens my locally stored html-pages by default. Firefox 113 was unable to display the files when I tried to open them via GIMP and via nautilus (it only displayed the pages when I searched for it in the Firefox browser by pressing ctrl+o). Firefox's update to 114 of 6/6/2023 solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I can access gimp-help packages after installing `gvfs-backends` in Kubuntu 23.04.

```
sudo apt install gvfs-backends
```

Gimp is installed via APT.

Answer (score 0):

To view the help pages of GIMP on Ubuntu 22.04 with the snap version, you can install the necessary help files by following these steps:

1. Open a terminal.
2. Run the following command to install the help files:

```
sudo apt install gimp-help-en
```

3. This command installs the English version of the GIMP help files.

After the installation is complete, you can access the help pages by launching GIMP and clicking on "Help" in the menu bar.

By installing the gimp-help-en package, you should be able to view the GIMP help pages within the application on your Ubuntu 22.04 system.